# Checking if form was actually submitted - Java/Selenium/TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to be able to check if a form is submitted and then if the form isn't submitted and an error message appears to print the error to the reporter log or logger.

My code is below for clicking a login button:please Check

```
  WebElement  login = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label")); 
  login button.
  if(login.isDisplayed()){

      login.click();

      Reporter.log("Login Form Submitted  | ");
      logger1.info("Submit Button Clicked");

  } else {
      Reporter.log("Login Failed  | ");
      Assert.fail("Login Failed - Check Data | ");       
  }
```

I'm passing in parameters to fill out the login form, I have set up one incorrect value in my data provider, however, when it gets to this bit of code the form is always submitted so if the data is correct the code runs fine and prints login form successful etc.

If the login form doesn't submit but is clicked so you are returned to the same login screen with an error, The else part of the code is never printed?

So I need to be able to click the button if the button is clicked but failed to login then print the else to the logger/reporter log.

How do I get the else part of the code to print if login does not happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cross check login is done or not. for valid credentials try to cross check any message like welcome or may log out button etc.. if they are not display, fail it.

for wrong  credentials, cross check error message. if error message is displayed pass else it fail.

below is one example, where i am looking for message to display after clicked on button. it may help you to give good idea

```
 //System.setProperty("WebDriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium Webdrivers\\chromedriver_win_26.0.1383.0\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://seleniumtrainer.com/components/buttons/");

    driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click();

    //by using if condition to cross check
    try{

        if(driver.findElement(By.id("demo")).isDisplayed()==true){

            System.out.println("clicked correctly");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){

        System.out.println("U Clicked Button1 text is not displayed. so failing or throwing again to fail test");
        throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }

    //simply by using testng assertion
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("demo")).getText(), "U Clicked Button1");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have got the sequence of execution wrong.

1. Enter the form values
2. Click on login button if displayed
3. Check login button is displayed (This is for checking whether the form is submitted successfully or not.) If login button is displayed (form is not submitted) look for the error and print it.

Psuedo code should look like below.

```
// Enter the form values

// Check if login button and click on it to submit the form 
WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));
if (loginButton.isDisplayed) {
    loginButton.click();
    Reporter.log("Submit Button Clicked");
}

// Now check again for the login button. 
// If login button is displayed it means that the form submission
// is not successful and you have returned to the same page.
// We are using a try catch block here because if the element is not found
// ie. if form submission is successful NoSuchElementException would be thrown.
try {
    // Element has to be found again else StaleElementReferenceException
    // might be thrown because of page reload.
    loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("dijit_form_Button_1_label"));
    // if login button is found again, this means form submission is not successful
    Reporter.log("Form Not submitted");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Login button is not found. Form is submitted
    Reporter.log("Form submitted successfully");
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I can understand how this works, however now I am getting: Cannot instantiate class testNG.TestNGDataProvider @Sighil

Comment: Ok this works, however, its printing login failed to the reporter.log even no 3 out of 4 logins are successful? so its saying submit button is clicked which is true. When it gets to try block if login has been successful it print login failed from the try block and not login form submitted successfully from the catch section?